# I have 2 entities in my database, but hibernate return 6 of them -.-

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

my problem loooks like that. I create object survey, add to this object 2 question and for each of them i add 3 answer. I insert it to database using hibernate. Look to database, it is exactly like I said, 2 question, for each 3 answer. Then I execute getSurvey, on survey object i execute get getQuestionSet, and it return 6 question 3x first question and 3 x second queston. My code is here:  https://pastebin.com/XS23YLZZ my tables are here https://pastebin.com/ZfHw3G3U, and my get method

```
public Survey getSurveyByName(String name)
{
Session session = null;
Survey survey = null;
try {

session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
survey = session.byNaturalId(Survey.class).using("surveyName",name                )   .load ();

} catch(Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
// handle exception here
} finally {
try {if(session != null) session.close();} catch(Exception ex) {}
}
return survey;

} `
```

Can someone help me to fix it, that it gonna outpu only 2 question ?

Comment: your query does a join instead of creating a list of associated objects

Comment: U mean  @JoinColumn ?

Comment: what happens if you do select * from tblQuestion 6 or 2 rows?

Comment: in phpMyAdmin 2 it return 2 rows, in database evrything is correct.